# Referencing own property when defining generic type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a type where the return value of a function depends on the value of another property, is this possible?

As far as I can tell, it's impossible to reference the interface you are defining as you are defining it.

Another approach to this would be saving the `keyof T` in some kind of type (like `K in keyof T` or similar) to be reused later in the class, but that doesn't seem to work

This is essentially what I want to do (although `this` obviously does not work):

```
interface GenericType<T> {
  column: keyof T;
  genericFunction: () => T[this.column];
}
```

Let's say T has two keys:

```
a: number,
b: string
```

Then I want my generic type to be typed as

```
column: 'a',
genericFunction: () => number
```

and if column changes to `'b'` then `genericFunction` should return `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
interface GenericType<T, U extends keyof T> {
  column: U;
  genericFunction: () => T[U];
}
```

How to use it:

```
interface AB {
  a: number
  b: string
}

const a: GenericType<AB, "a"> = {
  column: "a",
  genericFunction() {
    return 12; // the compiler ensures the return value is a number
  }
};
```

Or, another way to use it with inference:

```
function makeGenType<T, U extends keyof T>(obj: T, propName: U): GenericType<T, U> {
  return {
    column: propName,
    genericFunction() {
      return obj[propName];
    }
  };
}

const genType = makeGenType({ a: 12, b: "ab" }, "b");
// Type of `genType` is: { column: "b", genericFunction: () => string }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is only halfway there. This will type the return as `number | string` if using my example above. I only want the type of the key that is actually used.
Seems what I want to do is tricky and I'm starting to understand why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Boivie I edited. If you specify the member name, then the return type is not an union.